# AlarmManager not from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

When i create `AlarmManager` inside `MainActivity` it works as it should. Another activity starts at a specified time:

```java
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, iterator, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, key, pendingIntent);
```

But if i do this not from `MainActivity`, but, for example, from `AlarmActivity` class itself, upon reaching a predetermined time, nothing happens.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(**this**, AlarmActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(**this**, ...);
```

The problem is most likely in a context, but what context should be, if the intent is not created from `MainActivity`? `MainActivity` may not be created because `Alarm Activity` can be run without launching the main application. I tried with `this` and with `Alarm Activity.this`, and with `getApplicationContext()`

**UPDATE**
I have a postpone button on alarmActivity. And when i press it alarm is updating and activity is closing.

```java
public void hold(View view)
{
    long hold = 0;
    long currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
        //hold = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        hold = 5000; //for test
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1)
        hold = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2)
        hold = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3)
        hold = 30 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4)
        hold = 60 * 60 * 1000;

    currentTime += hold;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currentTime, pendingIntent);

    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens ? You check if with your app open or closed.  And you leave the alarmActivity after scheduling alarm ?

Comment: I have a postpone button on alarmActivity. And when i press it alarm is updating and activity is closing. I've updated the question

Comment: It is easy to fix.
I did the same thing, only instead of opening activity I opened a service.

What you need to have is an BroadcastReciver, at a specific the broadcast reciever is called in that you can start your activity the context you get in Broadcast reciver.
I will now put the code in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your manifest, register a reciever like this :

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever" > </receiver>
```

Now create a class which extends broadcast receiver like this :

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Print("intent "+intent.getAction());
    Log.d("Alarm ", "Alarm triggered!");



    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityToOpen.class).putExtra("byAlarm","yes");
    context.startActivity(activityIntent); //start



}
```

}

And here is the code for alarm :

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)     DialerService.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Print("inside scheduleAlarm  "+interval);
    logger.writeLog("inside schedule alarm and interval is "+interval);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+oneHour*interval, getPendingIntent(yourContext,AlarmID));



 private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, int id) {
    Intent intent =  new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class)
            .putExtra("alarmId", id);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

In your pending intent you have to give the AlarmReceiver class instead of your activity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try :)

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. In addition I want to say that in my case i had to add `activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` in AlarmReceiver class to escape the exception _"Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag"_.

I have a question. How to pass extras created in AlarmActivity class through AlarmReceiver class? It works only if i create a bundle of extras directly in AlarmReceiver class.

Comment: About your ques, I did not understand.  You mean you want send extras to the receiver class when you create pending intent?

Comment: I guessed :) I used `intent.getExtras()` and now it works as it have to. Thanks again. I haven't got enough reputation score to give you +1, but I'll do it when I can.